# How to add class for values in specific columns that matches a given pattern in jQuery.DataTables?

Tags: datatables

I want to add a classname "red" to:

1. all values that are less than `10`.
2. Only for those in column `X`,`Y`...

How can I achieve this?

It looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using The callback  `createdRow` as follows :

This callback is executed when a TR element is created (and all TD child elements have been inserted), it used to format a particular row at draw time.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable({
        createdRow: function (row, data, index) {
            if (data[2] < 10) {
                $('td', row).eq(2).addClass('red');
            }
            
            if (data[3] < 10) {
                $('td', row).eq(3).addClass('red');
            }
        },
    });
});
```

```css
td.red {
     font-weight: bold;
     color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>B</th>
                <th>X</th>
                <th>Y</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>13</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>23</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>316.5454</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>7</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>15</td>
                <td>16.5454</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>10</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>316.5454</td>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```